# WIF SessionAuthenticationModule not executing correctly

Tags: wif

I have an odd situation occurring that I am trying to diagnose and would appreciate any advice on where to look.

I have an ASP.NET application using WIF that contains another ASP.NET application as a child in IIS 7.5. This child application contains a REST based web service. Accessing this service directly by pasting a URL into a browser will redirect to an ADFS sign in page. This is how I expect it to work. The odd part is that I have a second environment with the same applications and service deployed, and in this environment I am never redirected to the sign in page.

I have checked that all web.config files are identical, and also checked all IIS settings that I thought might be related. Browsing to web pages on the second environment requires a login, but not when browsing directly to the REST .svc file. I checked all HttpModules and Handler Mappings in IIS. I also enabled tracing of Microsoft.IdentityModel events and on the first environment can see a basic entries for a redirect to the STS. On the second environment I don't see any WIF events. The SessionAuthenticationModule appears to be called when I examine the data flow using IIS failed event tracing, but am not sure why it isn't requiring authentication.

I am familiar with cookie related issues with WIF and made sure that all cookieHandler settings were correct. I also closed browser windows and cleared all cookies to make sure the SessionAuthenticationModule wasn't seeing previous WIF cookies.

If you can think of anything else I should check please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and carefully examining the applicationHost.config files between the two servers I found out this was caused by a difference in the ordering of HTTP handlers. The ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 handler was picking up the request on one server and redirecting to ADFS. On the other server the svc-Integrated-4.0 handler was responding to the request first. You can read more about this behavior here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520479

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same application in two separate environments bound to the same instance of ADFS, the URL's must be different so I am puzzled by the statement "all web.config files are identical"?

Have you tried re-running FedUtil on the application that doesn't work?

Also check AppPool settings.